# How do you change the font to a new paragraph using Docx4j?

Tags: java, fonts, docx, docx4j

I have a DocxDocument class that has a static **ObjectFactory** object, static **WordprocessingMLPackage** object and a **MainDocumentPart** object. Ideally you would use this method like ***addTextWithFont("Arial", "Hello")***

I'm trying to create a method that adds a paragraph with the font that you pass it as parameter. I believe I need to add a RFonts object with a PhysicalFont to the Rpr, but it's not working.

```
    public void addTextWithFont(String fontName, String text) {
        PhysicalFont font = PhysicalFonts.get(fontName);
        RFonts fonts = factory.createRFonts();
        fonts.setAscii(fontName);

        // This is the object we will add
        P p = factory.createP();

        // Create object for first run and add it to the P object
        R run = factory.createR();
        p.getContent().add(run);

        // Create rpr object
        RPr rpr = factory.createRPr();
        rpr.setRFonts(fonts);
        run.setRPr(rpr);

        // Create text object
        Text t = factory.createText();
        t.setValue(text);
        run.getContent().add(t);

        this.mainDocumentPart.addObject(p);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need PhysicalFont. What you have looks good.

You might also add:

```
fonts.setCs(fontName);
fonts.setHAnsi(fontName);
```

And you can check your result with:

```
   System.out.println(XmlUtils.marshaltoString(p));
```

Remember, you can generate code like this from a suitable example using the docx4j Helper Word AddIn, or the docx4j webapp.